# Sticky/affix headers in Ionic Angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, sticky, affix

I am trying to implement a form in Ionic and Angular. The form is made up of several sections,each section having a title and some content. I want that when one section is active, its title to be fixed as a header,even if you scroll down, until no part of the section is visible.
I googled something and I read about ion-sticky and ion-affix but I couldn't get it right. At the moment my code looks something like

```
< ion-list>
 < section-button> Title 1 < /section-button>
 < div> Content 1 < /div>
 ...
 < section-button> Title 10 < /section-button>
 < div> Content 10 < /div>
< /ion-list>
```

How can I achieve this? I know that I may change the containers in order for it to work. Will you please tell me what I should do? Thanks!

Comment: Something like this? http://codepen.io/chalettu/pen/qEgXOJ

Comment: Yes.something like that. When I scroll down the second section and the last of the three 'test's is still visible,I want 'day2' to also be visible above.

Comment: I tried that way but it doesn't work